# Change Checkbox return values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox, ransack

I am designing a search page in Rails using Ransack and I need some help with check boxes.

I have several check boxes. Here is one of them.

> <%= f.check_box :if_bt_eq %>BT

I know that when a check box is ticked it returns 1 and 0 when not ticked.

Is there any way in which I can change the non-ticked return value to nil ?

If not, can you suggest some sort of alternative for this?

Thanks!

Update:

Here's the hashes that are passed when the search form submit button is clicked:

with the check box ticked:

> ...q%5Bif_bt_eq%5D=1&...

with the check box not ticked:

> ...q%5Bif_bt_eq%5D=0&...

I want the check box not ticked to be

> ...q%5Bif_bt_eq%5D=&...

Comment: please see your param those are passing after submitting form... Basically when u ticked a checkbox the param are passing with key = value , if you have not checked it then it wil pass a nil value ... please check.

Comment: Go write your own web browser and then make your users use it!

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box
set `unchecked_value=nil`